# Grass, Route Finding with Elevation Limits

Tags: grass-gis, routing, elevation

I've got GRASS (7.0) installed and I "play" with it on ocassion since I am far from a GIS pro. What I want to do is to find all road routes from a certain point limited by distance (path length, not point-to-point) and grade (elevation change per distance, e.g. 5% equals 5m rise per 100m traveled) profile. The purpose is to find bicycling routes suited to my training needs at a given time.

Since, again, I am not pro, base data must be freely available (OSM, USGS sources for Siskiyou County, CA, US) as must be any extra tools. I'm pretty sure that what I want to do is not extremely difficult; but I really have no idea where to begin. I'm reasonably competent at shell, SQL, Python, etc. coding if I've got a clue as to what algorithm to implement. Now, I need serious remedying my cluelessness. :)

Comment: No idea about Grass. What you can do is use a Dijkstra e.g. with GraphHopper and write custom Java code to fit your requirements. Should not be that difficult if you know Java as elevation and the other stuff is already imported.

Answer (score 1):

Since you appear to use a vector representation of the routes, you may

- first split it into short segments (in order to later have a representative view on slope etc), using [v.split](http://grass.osgeo.org/grass70/manuals/v.split.html);
- then add a new column to the attribute table of that road map: "slope double precision" using [v.db.addcolumn](http://grass.osgeo.org/grass70/manuals/v.db.addcolumn.html);
- eventually upload the respective road segment slopes to the attribute table of the road map using [v.to.db](http://grass.osgeo.org/grass70/manuals/v.to.db.html), option=slope, column=slope. Note that this comes in degree, not percent;
- if you want percent, you can recalculate that in the attribute table using [v.db.update](http://grass.osgeo.org/grass70/manuals/v.db.update.html);

Now your network is populated with data and you can "navigate" on it (graph analysis) using the slope column as variable. A series of network algorithms are provided: http://grass.osgeo.org/grass70/manuals/topic_network.html

Comment: Ok, breaking the problem down into parts... So, let me see if I understand correctly...

Comment: Ok, breaking the problem down into parts... So, let me see if I understand correctly... (1) Somehow find all routes within the given distance limits. (2) For each route, break the route into small, 10-100 meter segments and associate each segment with slope. (3) Filter routes by slope limits.  Is that generally correct?

Comment: Almost: just break the roads network into small segments globally, then do assignment of respective slopes etc.